# Реализовать отложенную отправку данных на сервер

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Приложение должно сохранять данные на appengine c endpoint сервисом. Может так получиться что во время работы отвалилось интернет или приложение начало работу когда интернета уже не было.

Нужно эти данные подсохранить и потом при появлении интернета отправить. Мне кажется что должна быть уже какая либа на этот счет.

Сейчас это реализовано как Service который стартуется в Application и запускает таймер. Таймер смотрит есть ли подключение, если да то отсылаем, если нет то подписываемся на обновление ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Все вроде работает, но как то криво. Я думаю многие сталкивались в необходимостью не потерять данные при отсутствии интернета

Comment: Таймер- диковатое решение. Скорей всего вам надо вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app

Comment: @АндроидАндроид слушатель восстановления связи реализован именно так. Таймер там для другого, причем я думаю он там не нужен пока. Нужен быдет если я не все сохраненные данные буду сразу кидать а если захочу порциями

Comment: пока что упрастил все до безобразия. прописал в манефесте ресивер на изменение статуса подключений. Раньше я его запускал сам. А в таске которым я отсылаю на сервер сделал вариант если связи нет то сохраняю локально и все. получаеться если всязь есть то все отсылаеться сразу на сервер. если нет то сохраняеться а когда вязь появиться то сработает ресивер

Answer (score 0):

Взаимодействие с сервером и организация очереди -- это две разные темы, поэтому и ответы нужно искать в разных местах. Как я понимаю, с запросом на сервер все хорошо, осталось повторить его, если он по какой-то причине не удался. Соответственно, нужно хранить статус (признак того, что еще есть данные на отправку) и сами данные.

Для отправки нужно использовать service. В service нужно проверить возможность соединения (наличие соединения, нахождение в doze mode) и попробовать его осуществить. Если опять неудача, то нужно запланировать запуск заново. Для этого можно использовать AlarmManager, который будет повторно запускать service ([подробно описано в документации](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)).

Также нужно не забыть возможность того, что между попытками телефон будет перезагружен. Поэтому имеет смысл поймать intent [android.intent.action.REBOOT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_REBOOT), сообщающий о перезагрузке, и запланировать запуск service для отправки.

Для решения таких задач в Android есть [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html), который умеет планировать и осуществлять синхронизацию в фоне. Но он непрост в реализации и для простых задач будет overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы вызывать отложенные действия, оптимальнее всего использовать WorkManager. Ему можно задать условия для запуска (заряженная батарея, интернет и т.п.), можно вызывать OneTimeRequest, а можно Periodical.

Более подробно разжевано, например, здесь: [StartAndroid.RU Курс по компонентам архитектуры](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html)